# or where clause - Laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this query:

```
if($keyword){
    array_push($where, ['name_en', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%']);
}
```

The problem is that I have and `name_fr` column and I need to use `OR` clause - `array_push($where, ['name_fr', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%'])`.

I can't use `->orWhere`, because I have many dynamic search fields - they may exists or not.

For the example:

```
if($fromPrice){
    array_push($where, ['price', '>=', $fromPrice]);
}
if($toPrice){
    array_push($where, ['price', '<=', $toPrice]);
}
```

And the query is:

```
$cars= Property::with(array(
    'photos'=>function($query){
            $query->select(['car_id', 'name']);
        }
))->where($where)->paginate(10);
```

I need to select `WHERE name_en LIKE %val% OR name_fr LIKE %val%` with another queries.

Is there a way to use somehow `where`, 'OR' and `LIKE` in the above way including another values from `$where` array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to achieve that a suggest you to divide your query as below and don't put your `keyword` condition within `$where` array:

```
$query = Property::with(array(
    'photos'=>function($query){
            $query->select(['car_id', 'name']);
        }
))->where($where);

if($keyword){

     $query = $query->where(function ($query) use ($keyword) {
                  $query->where('name_fr', 'like', $keyword)
                  ->orWhere('name_en', 'like', $keyword);
     });
}

$cars = $query->paginate(10);
```

Comment: The problem is that I have another sets of where. I have $where `['id' =>, ''... ]` `AND` (if keyword exists) WHERE `keyword` LIKE this column or `keyword` like another column. But I see I can't use ->where($where)->where( // keyword query)

Comment: If I remove the first query `Property::with`, the query by keyword works fine. With it doesn't. Without keyword first query works, of course.

Comment: Ok, I have made it with three parts. First check `if(count($where))`, then apply it, 2. check keyword and latest execute and it works fine. Thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

You can also go with

```
$propertyQuery = Property::query();
if($keyword){
   $propertyQuery->where(function($query) use ($keyword){
                    $query->where('name_fr', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')->orWhere('name_en', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%');
           });
         }
$cars = $propertyQuery->paginate(10);
```

Comment: The problem is that I have another sets of where. I have $where `['id' =>, ''... ]` `AND` (if keyword exists) WHERE `keyword` LIKE this column or `keyword` like another column.